# Efficient use of consumers with Spring Integration and WebSphere when using XA transactions

Tags: java, websphere, spring-integration, tibco, ems

I am using Spring Integration (2.2.0) with WebSphere (8.0.0.x), in order to send messages via JMS (Tibco EMS).

Communication between components is working fine, but we have observed huge latencies between the messaging hops. These are in line with what we see in the EMS logs:

```
2014-09-30 06:04:19.940 [user@host]: Destroyed consumer (connid=19202559, sessid=28728543, consid=328585032) on queue 'test.queue3.request'
2014-09-30 06:04:19.969 [user@host]: Created consumer (connid=19202564, sessid=28728551, consid=328585054) on queue 'test.queue2.request'
2014-09-30 06:04:20.668 [user@host]: Destroyed consumer (connid=19202562, sessid=28728549, consid=328585048) on queue 'test.queue1.request'
2014-09-30 06:04:20.733 [user@host]: Created consumer (connid=19202567, sessid=28728555, consid=328585071) on queue 'test.queue5.request'
2014-09-30 06:04:20.850 [user@host]: Destroyed consumer (connid=19202563, sessid=28728550, consid=328585051) on queue 'test.queue4.request'
2014-09-30 06:04:21.001 [user@host]: Destroyed consumer (connid=19202564, sessid=28728551, consid=328585054) on queue 'test.queue2.request'
2014-09-30 06:04:21.701 [user@host]: Created consumer (connid=19202571, sessid=28728561, consid=328585093) on queue 'test.queue3.request'
2014-09-30 06:04:21.762 [user@host]: Destroyed consumer (connid=19202567, sessid=28728555, consid=328585071) on queue 'test.queue5.request'
```

Apparently, consumers are constantly being destroyed and re-created. This is not only bad for EMS, but also it's killing the latency, as messages are not delivered until the consumer is back online.

This is how the consumers are defined:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="rawConnectionFactory" jndi-name="jms/QueueCF"/>

<bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
      class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver"/>

<bean id="connectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter"
      p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="rawConnectionFactory"
      p:username="${jms.internal.username}"
      p:password="${jms.internal.password}"/>

<bean id="taskExecutor"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor"
      p:workManagerName="wm/mc"
      p:resourceRef="false"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="adp1Container"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
    p:taskExecutor-ref="taskExecutor"
    p:destinationName="requestQueue1" p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
    p:destinationResolver-ref="jmsDestinationResolver"
    p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager" />

<jms:inbound-gateway id="jmsInAdapter1"
    request-channel="adapter1logic" container="adp1Container" />

<channel id="adapter1logic" />
```

**Update:**

This behaviour is related to the use of the transaction manager.

If we specify the connection to the EMS server directly in Spring (indicating there the host, port, user, password), consumers are still constantly recreated, but for some reason these recreations are not affecting the end-to-end latencies. Connections are apparently being managed better in Spring than in WAS.

- How to configure WAS so that consumers trigger as quick as in Spring?

If, along with the previous change, I also remove the reference to the transaction manager in the DefaultMessageListenerContainer, consumers stop destroying and constructing altogether.

- What could be the issue with WebSphere's transaction manager? Why are consumers destroying and constructing when WAS' transaction manager is in use? Is there any configuration that can be adjusted?

Answer (score 2):

You should not see consumers being recycled like that, unless your listener is throwing an exception. Container consumers a long-lived by default. I suggest you turn on DEBUG (or even TRACE) logging for the container to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Raised the logging level, but I don't see any exceptions. On further testing switching things on and off, I have identified the issue related to the use of transactions, with an eye on the the managed connections.

Comment: The DefaultMessageListenerContainer documentation states: _"Note that this listener container will automatically reobtain all JMS handles for each transaction in case of an external transaction manager specified, for compatibility with all J2EE servers (in particular JBoss). This non-caching behavior can be overridden through the "cacheLevel" / "cacheLevelName" property, enforcing caching of the Connection (or also Session and MessageConsumer) even in case of an external transaction manager being involved."_ Is that not what we are seeing here? However, setting cacheLevel="3" is not improving.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to wrap your connection factory with `CachingConnectionFactory` decorator and configure the session caching strategy:

```
<bean id="cacheConnFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
</bean>
```

Use the above connection factory in your DMLC along with `cacheLevel` settings as follows:

```
<bean id="adp1Container"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
    p:taskExecutor-ref="taskExecutor"
    p:destinationName="requestQueue1"
    p:connectionFactory-ref="cacheConnFactory"
    p:destinationResolver-ref="jmsDestinationResolver"
    p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager">
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheLevel" value="3" /> <!-- Consumer Level -->
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried that, pointing my DMLCs to a CachingConnectionFactory, which in turn points to a UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter, which points to the raw connection retrieved via JNDI. However, with that setup, consumers are not created for some reason (I can see that in the EMS admin console), so messages are not processed. No error on startup.

Comment: Have you tried all the options provided in my answer together? I mean cache strategy config in conn factory as well as sessionTransacted and cacheLevel.

Comment: Yes, I just tried all of them as you suggested. But the problem of the subscribers persist. They are in effect not listening from the EMS server.

Comment: Ok, just found out one can't use the CachingConnectionFactory in combination with the UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter, so a custom class has to be created, as per http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/117049-singleconnectionfactory-does-not-support-custom-username-and-password. I'll try that.

Comment: No luck, either just using CachingConnectionFactory, chaining a CachingConnectionFactory with a UserCredentials one, or with the class above. I always get the error: [10/2/14 14:56:54:679 BST] 000000f3 SystemErr     R 2715752 [adp1Container-1] WARN org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'requestQueue1' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Method setExceptionListener not permitted (even though I've specified an exceptionListener)

Comment: Method setExceptionListener not permitted, cause suggesting to remove the exception listener. Try by removing the exception listener.

Comment: I actually only added the exception listener once I saw this message. May WAS be appending an exception listener by itself? All in all, I don't see the CachingConnectionFactory ever working in WAS (at least, for consumers).